# Why XML NodeType is read as Text instead of Element

Tags: c#, xml

This is one of the first times I have tried to read from XML, and I am experiencing an issue with getting all elements of an XML document to be treated as the same `NodeType`.

Example XML:

```
<AFElement>
    <Name>InterfaceBuilderTestBreaker01</Name>
    <Template></Template>
    <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
</AFElement>
```

where all elements are to be treated as `NodeType.Element` but the `XmlReader` is treating only the Element PIInterface as a `NodeType.Text` instead of element.

The schema that the XML is supposed to be working against contains the definition of the PIInterface:

```
<xs:element name="Name" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="Template" type="xs:string" />
<xs:element name="PIInterface" type="xs:string"/>
```

The code that parses the xml and reads it into an object for us looks similar to:

```
while (reader.Read())
{
    switch (reader.NodeType)
    {
        case XmlNodeType.Element:
            switch (reader.Name)
            {
                case "PIInterface":
                    // move pointer to element value
                    reader.Read();
                    item.Interface = reader.Value;
                    // move pointer to end element
                    reader.Read();
                    break;
            }
    }
}
```

Is there a reason that this is happening?  I have seen it treat it both ways (Element or Text)  I am thinking the fast solution would be to add a case in the first `switch` for the `NodeType.Text` but this seems wrong on the grounds that it should always treat it the same.

Any help is always appreciated.

UPDATE:
After creating a simple parsing example to be posted here I was not seeing the same behavior between test XML files and actual XML files.  The XML seems to be similar but somehow they are not the same.

Working XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Element xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ExampleParse.xsd">
  <AFElement>
    <Name>ExampleParseName01</Name>
    <Template>ExampleParseTemplate</Template>
    <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
    <AFElement>
      <Name>ExampleParseName06</Name>
      <Template>ExampleParseTemplate</Template>
      <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
      <AFElement>
        <Name>ExampleParseName07</Name>
        <Template>ExampleParseTemplate</Template>
        <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
        <AFElement>
          <Name>ExampleParseName08</Name>
          <Template>ExampleParseTemplate</Template>
          <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
        </AFElement>
      </AFElement>
    </AFElement>
  </AFElement>
  <AFElement>
    <Name>ExampleParseName02</Name>
    <Template>ExampleParseTemplate</Template>
    <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
  </AFElement>
</Element>
```

Non working XML:

```
<Element xmlns="http://tempuri.org/ExampleParse.xsd">
  <AFElement>
    <Name>InterfaceBuilderTestBreaker01</Name>
    <Template></Template>
    <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
    <AllAttributes>
      <AFAttribute name="classic">
        <field name="ptclassname" value="ModbusE"/>
        <field name="pointsource" value="InterfaceBuilder01"/>
        <field name="instrumenttag" value="192.168.1.100"/>
      </AFAttribute>
    </AllAttributes>
    <AFElement>
      <Name>InterfaceBuilderTestBreaker02</Name>
      <Template></Template>
      <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
      <AllAttributes>
        <AFAttribute name="classic">
          <field name="ptclassname" value="ModbusE"/>
            <field name="pointsource" value="InterfaceBuilder01"/>
            <field name="location1" value="1"/>
            <field name="location2" value="2"/>
            <field name="location3" value=""/>
            <field name="location4" value="2"/>
            <field name="location5" value=""/>
            <field name="instrumenttag" value="192.168.1.100"/>
        </AFAttribute>
      </AllAttributes>
    </AFElement>
    <AFElement>
      <Name>InterfaceBuilderTestBreaker03</Name>
      <Template></Template>
      <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
      <AllAttributes>
         <AFAttribute name="classic">
            <field name="ptclassname" value="ModbusE"/>
            <field name="pointsource" value="InterfaceBuilder01"/>
            <field name="location1" value="1"/>
            <field name="location2" value="3"/>
            <field name="location3" value=""/>
            <field name="location4" value="3"/>
            <field name="instrumenttag" value="192.168.1.100"/>
         </AFAttribute>
       </AllAttributes>
    </AFElement>
    <AFElement>
      <Name>InterfaceBuilderTestMeter01</Name>
      <Template></Template>
      <PIInterface>ModbusE</PIInterface>
      <AllAttributes>
         <AFAttribute name="classic">
           <field name="ptclassname" value="ModbusE"/>
           <field name="pointsource" value="InterfaceBuilder02"/>
           <field name="instrumenttag" value="192.168.1.101"/>
           <field name="exdesc" value=""/>
         </AFAttribute>
      </AllAttributes>
     </AFElement>
   </AFElement>
</Element>
```

I would not have thought that the element of `<AllAttributes>` would cause the `<PIInterface>` element to be treated differently.  Other differences are the non working XML is generated from a script from cells in Excel and the test elements I put together by hand.  I do not see any difference in the output that would account for the varied treatment or the elements.

Have I missed something?

Note: The XML is a hierarchy of elements that when parsed should return a list of each element removing the hierarchy.  It is for this reason that I delved down into the low level interface.  I am open to rewriting the parsing function to use different interfaces, but until now it worked as expected.

UPDATE 2:
As per the comment from keshlam, a full example code block:

```
private static void internalParser(XmlReader reader, ref int c, ref ObservableCollection<DataHolder> List)
    {
        DataHolder data = new DataHolder();
        data.Title = "Interface" + c;
        c++;
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            switch (reader.NodeType)
            {
                case XmlNodeType.Element:
                    switch (reader.Name)
                    {
                        case "Name":
                            // move pointer to element value
                            reader.Read();

                            data.InterfaceName = reader.Value;
                            // move pointer to end element
                            reader.Read();
                            break;
                        case "Template":
                            // move pointer to element value
                            reader.Read();
                            data.ElementTemplate = reader.Value;
                            // move pointer to end element
                            reader.Read();
                            break;
                        case "PIInterface":
                            // move pointer to element value
                            reader.Read();
                            data.ElementInterface = reader.Value;
                            // move pointer to end element
                            reader.Read();
                            break;
                        case "AFElement":
                            // create new object for processing
                            internalParser(reader, ref c, ref List);
                            break;
                    }
                    break;
                case XmlNodeType.EndElement:
                    if (reader.Name == "AFElement")
                    {
                        List.Add(data) ;
                        return ;
                    }
                    break;
            }
        }
        return ;
    }
```

Comment: Use XLINQ; it's much easier to use.

Comment: Are you sure that what you're reading is actually XML structure, as opposed to something that has been escaped or quoted so it *is* text? (If it's wrapped in a CDATA Section, for example...)

Comment: @keshlam The example is a direct copy/paste from the xml file.

Comment: If so, I have to assume that the problem is in your code. A minimal runnable sample that demonstrates the failure might (a) help us diagnose it and (b) help you diagnose it.

Comment: Are you sure that direct use of the low-level interfaces offered by an XML pull parser is the best way of writing your application? Can't you use a high-level language designed for XML, like XSLT, XQuery, or LINQ; or data binding; or even the DOM? I think that as a beginner, you've probably chosen the wrong approach (but not knowing your problem, one can't be sure).

Comment: I agree with everyone that this sounds like a data issue.  And I agree with @michaelkay that I would recommend exploring one of the .net or third-party xml objects.  If you have an xml reader loaded, you could make an XmlDocument, for example, and have direct access to any node you want.  And you could still loop through it if it's absolutely necessary.

Comment: I am experiencing something very similar.